# Xamarin Android Drawable Navbar Item Clickable

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin, I'm trying to figure out that when I click on one of the item on the navbar it would proceed to another activity or another layout but I've tried to used the switch but it doesn't make changes. Here is my code

> MainActivity.cs

```
 public class MainDashboard : AppCompatActivity
    {
        Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar mainToolbar;
        Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(PediburRatingApp.Resource.Layout.MainDashboard);
            // Create your application here
            ConnectControl();
        }
        void ConnectControl()
        {
            drawerLayout = (Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.drawerLayout);
            mainToolbar = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar)FindViewById(Resource.Id.mainToolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(mainToolbar);
            SupportActionBar.Title = "";
            Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBar actionBar = SupportActionBar;
            actionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Mipmap.ic_menu_action);
            actionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {

                case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
                    drawerLayout.OpenDrawer((int)GravityFlags.Left);
                    return true;

                case Resource.Id.navProfile:

                    return true;
                default:
                    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

> Main Activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            layout="@layout/include_main"
 />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/headerLayout"
        app:menu="@menu/navmenu"
    />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

If I've done wrong please correct me

> Here is the Navmenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--For all properties see: https://aka.ms/android-menu-resource-->
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <group>
    <item
      android:id="@+id/navProfile"
      android:title="Profile"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_person_action"
      />
    <item
  android:id="@+id/navRating"
  android:title="Rate a Driver"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_person_action"
      />
    <item
  android:id="@+id/navTopDriver"
  android:title="Weekly Driver"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_person_action"
      />
    <item
  android:id="@+id/navBalance"
  android:title="View Balance"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_person_action"
      />
    <item
  android:id="@+id/navAbout"
  android:title="About"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_person_action"
      />

  </group>

</menu>
```

Comment: Did you add the the click listener for your `NavigationView`? like following code `navigationView.SetNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);` and do not forget to achieve the `NavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` interface. override the `OnNavigationItemSelected` method. You can create a Navigationdrawer demo by VS like following screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/IP1drF0

Comment: I've followed your instructions now how do I open new activity when clicked but still having the navbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF?

[image]

If so, you can achieve it by `Fragment`

Here is code. when switch Fragments.

```
      public bool OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.ItemId;

        FragmentTransaction transaction = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();


        if (id == Resource.Id.nav_camera)
        {
            // Handle the camera action

        }
        else if (id == Resource.Id.nav_gallery)
        {
            fragment = new Fragment1();

        }
        else if (id == Resource.Id.nav_slideshow)
        {
            fragment = new Fragment2();

        }
        else if (id == Resource.Id.nav_manage)
        {

        }
        else if (id == Resource.Id.nav_share)
        {

        }
        else if (id == Resource.Id.nav_send)
        {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.CloseDrawer(GravityCompat.Start);
        transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.FramePage, fragment);
        transaction.Commit();
        return true;
    }
```

Here is my demo(For testing, I just create two Fragments(Gallery and slidehow tab)), you can refer to it.

https://github.com/851265601/XAndroidFragmentAndNavigationVIew